# Как импортировать библиотеку string в Cython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

Всем привет!

Есть такой файл pyx

```
cdef extern from "Person.h" namespace "person":
    cdef cppclass CppPerson:
        CppPerson() except +
        CppPerson(string name, int age) except +


cdef class Person:
    cdef CppPerson *cpp_person

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.cpp_person = new CppPerson()
        if self.cpp_person == NULL:
            raise MemoryError('Not enough memory.')

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.cpp_person
```

*В четвёртой строчке мне надо использовать тип string*

**Как мне импортировать библиотеку string?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`from libcpp.string cimport string`](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html#c-strings)